# Microsoft Commerce Server 2007 ebook

Tags: microsoft-commerce-server

As I'm a beginner, I need to download some good tutorials/e-books on MS-Commerce server 2007. Can anyone help me with some links?

Thanks in advance

Koushik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found quite a few blogs worth looking into:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/maxakbar/
[Max Akbar]

http://blog.brianh.dk/
[Brian Holmgård Kristensen]

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinayakt/
[Vinayak Tadas]

http://www.gaelduhamel.com/
[Gael Duhamel]

http://www.victorocastro.com/
[Victor O. Castro]

http://www.lewisbenge.net/
[Lewis Benge]

http://microsoftblog.co.in/commerceserver/
[Ravi Kanth]

http://ecommerceondotnet.blogspot.com/
[Stelio Di Bello]

Answer (score 0):

I've read the docs. They are extensive, free and pretty good. Read those.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are no Commerce Server 2007 eBooks.  I do know of the following resources:

- [Commerce Server 2007 MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms864793%28v=cs.70%29.aspx)
- [Commerce Server 2007 book (UK Amazon only)](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Software-Smiths-Commerce-Server-2007-Smith/dp/3837038564/) *I have not read this, so cannot comment on quality*

There are also a few blogs of varying age and quality.  I suggest you Google on more specific Commerce Server sub-systems as you read about them (or start developing with them).

*I did link to other online resources.  However, as an SO newbie I may only add two links per answer.*